# C fgets read lines

Tags: c, caching, stdin, fgets

please, could you help me, how to read lines from stdin via fgets? Problem is, that sometimes in tmp_string are stored part of data from two lines before etc... I'm using this code to load line:

```
int loadLine(Line *line) {
    char tmp_string[MAX_LOAD];
    int return_val;
    return_val = 0;
    line->length = MAX_LOAD;
    line->index = 0;
    line->data = (char*) malloc(sizeof (char) * line->length);

    while (fgets(tmp_string, MAX_LOAD - 1, stdin) != NULL) {
        strncat(line->data, tmp_string, MAX_LOAD);
        line->index += strlen(tmp_string);
        if (tmp_string[strlen(tmp_string) - 1] == '\n') { /* if I'm at the end of line... */
            line->data[strlen(line->data) - 1] = '\0';
            return_val = 1;
            break;
        }
        if ((line->index + MAX_LOAD) > line->length) {
            resizeLine(line);
        }

    }

    if(feof(stdin))
    {
        return_val = 0;
    }

    return return_val;
}
```

And here is usage:

```
Line line;
if(loadLine(&line) == 0){ ... }
free(line.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line->data` has not been initialised (no terminator), so `strncat()` can fail.

```
line->data = malloc(sizeof (char) * line->length);
line->data[0] = 0;
```

Comment: I think probably not.  Note that after the `strncat()`, there is code that appears intended to ensure that there is at least `MAX_LOAD` bytes available in `line->data`.

Comment: Note the length check and the call to `resizeLine()`.  This could certainly allocate more space to `line->data`, or allocate a separate, larger block, copy the contents of `line->data` to it, and assign it to `line->data`.  Via `realloc()`, for instance.

Comment: The lack of a terminator in `line->data` is a good catch, though, and the likely cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. After I add the second line you post, it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question you posed, your usage of `fgets()` looks reasonable, though you are wasting one byte of your `tmp_string` variable.  The `fgets()` function already knows to reserve one byte for a trailing NUL, so if you are reading into an array of length `MAX_LOAD` then you would normally use

```
fgets(tmp_string, MAX_LOAD, stdin);
```

This will overwrite the previous contents of the destination buffer (`tmp_string`) up to the number of bytes read plus one, and it will automatically add a string terminator after the last byte read.  If a previously read line was longer then its tail might remain in the buffer, but that shouldn't matter because the standard string functions will ignore anything after the terminator.

The misbehavior you see is very likely caused by your failure to initialize `line->data` to a zero-length string before passing it to `strncat()`, as Weather Vane observed first.